# JS: GET request with added "data" parameter like cURL -d '{key: value, key2: value}'

Tags: javascript, curl, httprequest, react-redux, axios

I am using `react-redux` combo and `axios` along with it to do GET requests.
I however, need to do requests with an added 'data' attribute.

Just like how `cURL` does a get request using `-d` flag.

eg. `cURL <...> -d '{"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}'`

Axios documentation, however says that only `POST`, `PUT` etc. can have a `'data'` option. `GET`does not support this.

What JS lib/tool should I use to do this within react-redux?

Any suggestion?

Comment: axios allows you to do that.Just pass in data param and it will work, just how it works when you do a post.

Comment: @VivekN Are have you used the 'data' with a GET? because the doc says it allows a `data` section only in 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'...

Comment: You can send all your data object inside params key of axios.
For example: -axios.get('http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq', {
    params: {
     query: 'tehran',
     name: 'vivek nayyar'
    }
   })
   .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
   })
 }

Comment: Using curl in linux I can use the -d option and force a GET request using -X GET

Answer (score 0):

You can't append data in the same way with a GET request that you can with POST and PUT. That's part of the underlying http spec.

You need to include your data package as a query parameter. There's a few ways to do it, such as the following:

```
const package = JSON.stringify({"key1": "value", "key2": "value"})
axios.get('/user?ID=12345&data=' + escape(package))
```

Then in the backend you would unescape and JSON.parse the `data`.

Ideally though, you shouldn't be doing this. POST and PUT are specifically designed for this role and allow you to send large amounts of data. Those request types are also meant to create or update a remote resource, respectively. GET is mean to retrieve a resource defined at a URI, not to change/create/update it.

Comment: I read that recently and as I pointed out earlier, it allows but not in GET request. That is the problem..

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I definitely understand the design considerations for GET. However, the `data` being sent is for refining a search/query.. So I don't get why it is not supported. Not much I can do I guess.

Comment: Its not supported because that's not how it was designed to work. Like I said, if you *have* to use GET like this then your data has to be a parameter in the query string.